# How is this function passed an argument with no parameter?

Tags: python, scope, closures

I'm currently learning about closure and this code was presented:

```py
def outer_func(x):
    y = 4
    def inner_func(z):
        print(f"x = {x}, y = {y}, z = {z}")
        return x + y + z
    return inner_func

for i in range(3):
    closure = outer_func(i)
    print(f"closure({i+5}) = {closure(i+5)}")
```

I understand `x` is defined at the point `outer_func` is assigned to  `closure`, and `y` is defined within the function each time. My question is how is `z` defined? Shouldn't the call to `closure` overwrite the value of `x`? How does python know to assign this new value to `z`?

Comment: `outer_func` returns the `inner_func`, so the parameter you pass when calling `closure` is `z`.

Comment: Isn't the output pretty clear - when you call `closure(i+5)` inside f-string, you pass z=i+5

Comment: The value for z comes from, `print(f"closure({i + 5}) = {closure(i + 5)}")`. Functions in python are "first class functions", which means that you can kind of treat them like variables. `closure` is a first class function here, and you are calling the function in that line mentioned above with a value of `i + 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how is `z` defined?

`z` is a parameter of `inner_func`. It means it's always local to the `inner_func` function(local variable). When the `outer_func` function is called the body of it will be executed, which indeed first **create** `inner_func` and give you back a reference to it. Then whatever you pass to `inner_func`, it uses as the `z`. It's a normal argument passing.

> Shouldn't the call to closure overwrite the value of `x`?

`inner_func` is your closure. It has access to it's enclosing scope which is `outer_func`. `x` is a parameter of `outer_func`, it gets it's value from executing the line:

```py
closure = outer_func(i)
```

So whatever you pass to `outer_func` becomes available to the `inner_func`'s body. (Closure mechanism)

> How does python know to assign this new value to z?

I already answered this in the first part. In the line:

```py
print(f"closure({i+5}) = {closure(i+5)}")
```

you are passing the value of `z` in `closure(i+5)` part.

Q: Now where does `inner_func` get `y`'s value from? A: Again it's a closure, it has access to `outer_func` namespace. `y` is always defined when `outer_func()` is called. Nothing can change it's value in your code. That loop can only change `x` because it comes from outside. (argument)

Comment: This is the explanation I needed, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is:

> I understand x is defined at the point outer_func is assigned to closure, and y is defined within the function each time. My question is how is z defined? Shouldn't the call to closure overwrite the value of x? How does python know to assign this new value to z?

Your code is:

```
def outer_func(x):
    y = 4
    def inner_func(z):
        print(f"x = {x}, y = {y}, z = {z}")
        return x + y + z
    return inner_func

for i in range(3):
    closure = outer_func(i)
    print(f"closure({i+5}) = {closure(i+5)}")
```

The call to `closure` is effectively a call to `inner_func` (not `outer_func`) and the argument passed to `closure` will be assigned to `z` (not `x`).

**Explanation:**

Each execution of `closure = outer_func(i)` does the following:

- call `outer_func()` thereby effectively assigning the passed argument `i` to the variable `x` in the scope of `outer_func()`
- execute `y = 4`
- leave `outer_func()` with a return value of type function whose value is `inner_func`
- assign the return value of `outer_func()` (namely the function `inner_func`) to `closure`, with ongoing access to the variables in the containing scope of `inner_func()` (namely, the scope of `outer_func()`).

Each call to `closure()` within the `for` loop does the following:

- call `inner_func()` thereby assigning the passed argument to `z` in the scope of `inner_func()`
- execute the body of `inner_func()` where `x` and `y` have the values they had at the time of the call to `outer_func()` that created this copy of `inner_func` as a closure.

Comment: @Mr.Lupine Do you need any more help with your question?

Comment: No this is great, thanks! Essentially by making outer_func return inner_func without calling the function, closure = inner_func(z)?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I would put it this way: by making outer_func return inner_func (without calling it), closure = outer_func(x) has the effect of making closure be a reference to inner_func such that executing closure(z) is equivalent to executing inner_func(z) with the important additional feature that variables in the containing scope of inner_func (that is, local to outer_func) have the same values they did at initialization of closure.